# How to get reference of active view in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I am new to android..

Is there any way to get the reference of active View loaded in the android...?
I want it  some like this:::

```
View v=getTheActiveView();
bool b = v.getKeepScreenOn();//
```

I want this method `getTheActiveView` to be implemented.

This view may be **Android home screen,or some other Application's view**...
I dont want setter methods,just getter methods like `getKeepScreenOn`,etc is enough...

Pardon me if it is blunder...

Answer (score 0):

If you added a tag to the view in question (whether you inflated it from an xml layout file or created it programmatically), you can call `findViewById(int id)` on the Activity that the view is currently displayed in to get a reference to it. Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Actually i want reference of **any** view that is currently active....whether it is my application's view or any other application's view or even android homescreen...I dont know whether it is possible or not..

Comment: For security reasons you cannot access other's applications views.